# Runing yarn start in a react app: the developement view in the browser never loads and i get this error:

Tags: exec, yarnpkg, bin

bash: \wsl$\Ubuntu\home\murkhunting.vscode-server\bin\ea3859d4ba2f3e577a159bc91e3074c5d85c0523/node: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
/usr/bin/bash: Exit 126.

Comment: I just got the same (except for the `murkhunting` part of course), including same `ea3859d4...` directory name. This is a regression for me; was working at the end of last week, encountered the error when reran today. Mine is an expo react native project; curious if yours is too @Murkhunting? (could help narrow focus of where the error is)

Comment: @Markhunting did you explore others commenting about the same problem? i.e. search hits for `ea3859d4ba2f3e577a159bc91e3074c5d85c0523`? e.g. [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/4212), [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/4258), [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/kffqcr/after_upgrading_to_vscode_1521_unable_to_connect/)

Comment: I strongly suspect this error is related to others reporting new problems with browser.sh in VSCode 1.52, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/65774451/135114. Note the title of the bash window displaying the error contains the whole bash command being run, which is running the vscode server helper `browser.sh`

Comment: @Markhunting you should update your question to give more info if you don't want it to be closed. 1) OS, environment, VSCode version, etc. 2) What you found in searching / tried

Answer (score 0):

Workaround (for people coming here by searching this problem)

run  `unset BROWSER`  before running `yarn start` will solve this problem